# error in union query defining aliases

Tags: mysql

I am extracting the same informations from three different tables: I need to get all the data in one table grouping the results as in each single query. The query I wrote is the following:

```
SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(totali) FROM 
SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(fa_ce_ca.importo) AS totali FROM fatture, fa_ce_ca,centri_costoricavo, movimenti WHERE fatture.esercizio=3 AND fatture.id_fa=fa_ce_ca.id_fa AND centri_costoricavo.id=fa_ce_ca.centro AND movimenti.id=fa_ce_ca.caus GROUP BY fa_ce_ca.caus AS fatture 
UNION SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(mov_banca.importo) AS totali FROM mov_banca,centri_costoricavo, movimenti,esercizi WHERE centri_costoricavo.id=mov_banca.centro AND movimenti.id=mov_banca.tipo AND mov_banca.data BETWEEN esercizi.start AND esercizi.end AND esercizi.id=3 AND mov_banca.per=2 GROUP BY mov_banca.tipo AS mov_banca 
UNION SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(mov_cassa.importo) AS totali FROM mov_cassa,centri_costoricavo, movimenti,esercizi WHERE centri_costoricavo.id=mov_cassa.centro AND movimenti.id=mov_cassa.tipo AND mov_cassa.data BETWEEN esercizi.start AND esercizi.end AND esercizi.id=3 AND mov_cassa.per=2 GROUP BY mov_cassa.tipo) AS mov_cassa 
GROUP BY movimenti.movimento
```

Trying to execute the query I get the following error: "... the right syntax to use near 'AS mov_banca UNION (S...". After hours banging my head against the wall I can't see what I am doing wrong. Any help?

Thanks in advance!
Lelio

Comment: try simplifying your query and running just certain parts of it to isolate the issue.  also, check your parentheses and i'm not sure you can have multiple tables named `mov_cassa` or `mov_banca` in the same scope (i'm not sure if you do or not but it's something to check).  also... formatting might help?  http://sqlformat.appspot.com/  ohh and i wonder if you can even use table aliases in a `union` situation like that.  and the table created by all those `union`s does need an alias for the outermost `from` statement.

Comment: and in your select... neither table `centri_costoricavo` or table `movimenti` exist in that scope... just that one large table made from the `union` statements (that doesn't have a name).  I think maybe you meant to `join` instead of `union`...?   Maybe?

Comment: you have to use aliases for the derived tables (required by mysql). Each subquery is working like a charm. The issue is coming from the union stuff. For the formatting... I am still a newbie with stackoverflow writing code ;)

Comment: the three subtables must be appended one to the other (union). In the main select i could have used *...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the parentheses around the SELECT query in each union. The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT <column-list>
FROM {<table>|<derived-table>} [[AS] <alias>]
[UNION [ALL]
 SELECT <column-list>
 FROM {<table>|<derived-table>} [[AS] <alias>]
]*
```

Note you would still need parentheses around the *derived-table subquery*, just not the parts of the union.

Also, in attempting to format your query it looks like you have funny things going on with parentheses and subqueries. I believe you want the sum from the union, and also most likely want a `UNION ALL` and **not** a `UNION`. You also need to select from the entire derived-table subquery (I've gone and named it `X` in the example below)

Therefore, your query should (probably) be:

```
SELECT X.descrizione, X.movimento, sum(totali) 
FROM (
    SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(fa_ce_ca.importo) AS totali 
    FROM fatture, fa_ce_ca,centri_costoricavo, movimenti 
    WHERE fatture.esercizio=3 
    AND fatture.id_fa=fa_ce_ca.id_fa 
    AND centri_costoricavo.id=fa_ce_ca.centro 
    AND movimenti.id=fa_ce_ca.caus 
    GROUP BY fa_ce_ca.caus
    UNION ALL
    SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(mov_banca.importo) AS totali 
    FROM mov_banca,centri_costoricavo, movimenti,esercizi 
    WHERE centri_costoricavo.id=mov_banca.centro 
    AND movimenti.id=mov_banca.tipo 
    AND mov_banca.data BETWEEN esercizi.start AND esercizi.end 
    AND esercizi.id=3 
    AND mov_banca.per=2 
    GROUP BY mov_banca.tipo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(mov_cassa.importo) AS totali 
    FROM mov_cassa,centri_costoricavo, movimenti,esercizi 
    WHERE centri_costoricavo.id=mov_cassa.centro 
    AND movimenti.id=mov_cassa.tipo 
    AND mov_cassa.data BETWEEN esercizi.start AND esercizi.end 
    AND esercizi.id=3 
    AND mov_cassa.per=2 
    GROUP BY mov_cassa.tipo
) AS X
GROUP BY X.movimento
```

Although you *still* have **very weird** (read: MySQL-only, hackish, horrible to understand and frankly unpredictable) `GROUP BY`s  and your choice of using the "old" JOIN syntax makes your query even harder to read.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it is a union all query of course! Thanks also for the advice on the join sintax, I'll have a look on how to rewrite it. It is an internal tool intended to be used only by me so I look first to the result ;)

Comment: The alias, in that case, are not necessary but they are kind od documentation. They show the intent, what is extracted on each query.

Answer (score 0):

I took your query and formatted it to

```
SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(totali) 
FROM ( (SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(fa_ce_ca.importo) AS totali 
        FROM fatture, fa_ce_ca,centri_costoricavo, movimenti 
        WHERE fatture.esercizio=3 AND fatture.id_fa=fa_ce_ca.id_fa AND centri_costoricavo.id=fa_ce_ca.centro AND movimenti.id=fa_ce_ca.caus 
        GROUP BY fa_ce_ca.caus
       ) AS fatture 
       UNION 
       (SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(mov_banca.importo) AS totali 
        FROM mov_banca,centri_costoricavo, movimenti,esercizi 
        WHERE centri_costoricavo.id=mov_banca.centro AND movimenti.id=mov_banca.tipo AND mov_banca.data BETWEEN esercizi.start AND esercizi.end AND esercizi.id=3 AND mov_banca.per=2 
        GROUP BY mov_banca.tipo
       ) AS mov_banca 
       UNION
      (SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(mov_cassa.importo) AS totali 
        FROM mov_cassa,centri_costoricavo, movimenti,esercizi 
        WHERE centri_costoricavo.id=mov_cassa.centro AND movimenti.id=mov_cassa.tipo AND mov_cassa.data BETWEEN esercizi.start AND esercizi.end AND esercizi.id=3 AND mov_cassa.per=2 
       GROUP BY mov_cassa.tipo) AS mov_cassa
      ) 
GROUP BY movimenti.movimento
```

It seems you're missing a parenthesis...

```
SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(totali) 
--
-- 2 opening parenthesis.
--
FROM ( (SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(fa_ce_ca.importo) AS totali 
        FROM fatture, fa_ce_ca,centri_costoricavo, movimenti 
        WHERE fatture.esercizio=3 AND fatture.id_fa=fa_ce_ca.id_fa AND centri_costoricavo.id=fa_ce_ca.centro AND movimenti.id=fa_ce_ca.caus 
        GROUP BY fa_ce_ca.caus
       ) AS fatture 
       UNION 
       (SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(mov_banca.importo) AS totali 
        FROM mov_banca,centri_costoricavo, movimenti,esercizi 
        WHERE centri_costoricavo.id=mov_banca.centro AND movimenti.id=mov_banca.tipo AND mov_banca.data BETWEEN esercizi.start AND esercizi.end AND esercizi.id=3 AND mov_banca.per=2 
        GROUP BY mov_banca.tipo
       ) AS mov_banca 
       UNION
      (SELECT centri_costoricavo.descrizione, movimenti.movimento, sum(mov_cassa.importo) AS totali 
        FROM mov_cassa,centri_costoricavo, movimenti,esercizi 
        WHERE centri_costoricavo.id=mov_cassa.centro AND movimenti.id=mov_cassa.tipo AND mov_cassa.data BETWEEN esercizi.start AND esercizi.end AND esercizi.id=3 AND mov_cassa.per=2 
       GROUP BY mov_cassa.tipo) AS mov_cassa
      ) 
   ) temp   --   <----------------  Is it missing ?
GROUP BY temp.movimento
```

Comment: sorry, what's temp for? Anyway i don't see where did you open the last parenthesis

Comment: the temp is needed to alias the UINIONs. I added some comments where are opening parenthesis.

Comment: yep, you are right. The union table is the fourth derived table and so needs the alias too!!